# If the bible says 'Thou shalt not judge' why do people judge LGBT lifestyle?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, christianity

It's something that puzzles me. It's like the bible says one thing, but then many people turn it around and use it to bash other people with it.

I've also seen so-called Christians make lies, and the bible says 'thou shalt not lie'. So, you can't have it both ways. In my opinion, if you want to be a Christian, you have to do exactly what the bible says.

Is religion a form of hypocracy?

Comment: It seems this is trying to promote a personal philosophy rather than ask a question that could be answered in a few paragraphs. So I am going to vote to close, however, I hope you come back with more questions that perhaps address your concern here indirectly say by asking a question about a particular philosopher or text.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. First of the bible is not ment to be interpreted literally. Second the christian theology states that only jesus could live a "perfect" live and that his followers should try to emulate it. Jesus dies to save those that emulate him but fail due to their human nature. You can disagree with the stance they take but calling them hipocrits seems to missunderstand the christian doctrine that addresses the issue at hand.

Comment: Bible is extremenly self-contradicting. It is so self-contradictory that the first contradiction can be found as soon as in Book of Genesis 1:4-5 vs 1:14. And regarding lies... not everything is done and made consciously.

Comment: Because people act inconsistent with theory does not make the theory useless.  All people will likely fit the hypocrite status at some point.  No one is capable of following ALL ten commandments.  Only Jesus could fulfill.

Comment: @Logikal, why do you think so? Why do you think Jesus did [fulfill] and, say, Moses and other prophets didn't?

Comment: This seems like a better fit for Christianity SE. You can try Judaism SE too.

Comment: Jesus was the only person who had the full spirit of God dwelling in the human flesh. This means no matter how hard one tries you can't be equal. Jesus also is the only person without sin. That is he was not born into sin like we are and never committed sin. Jesus is equivalent to God in many religious sects & not an ordinary human being like us.

Comment: Same reason they judge pedos or zoophiles.  Religion a form of hypocracy ? Of course it is.

Comment: I believe that modern theologians are more likely to avoid discussing the issue of homosexuality as opposed to the older theologians who outright condemned homosexuality. However, William Lane Criag isn't supportive of same-sex marriage and might have supported Trump.

Comment: There is a difference between seeing a certain behaviour as improper and judging others for indulging in it. Religion is not hypocracy but many religious people are hypocrites. Avoiding hypocracy is very difficult and I often fail.

Comment: @Logikal, I think this explains a lot of your position here regarding philosophy. I reject the notion of sin amd therefore Jesus was not the only one without sin. Also, the position of original sin came into christianity later and original sin was a counter-argument for christianity.

Comment: If people didn't judge there wouldn't need to be a rule in the Bible against it. There's no rule that says we can't flap our arms and fly. That's because there's no need for such a rule. If you want to know the kind of things people do, just look at the rules that describe what they're not allowed to do.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am 100% LGBTQIA2S+ affirming. I make my humble biases known, to allow for a more objective understanding of my background.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take what the Bible says in context. This is what Jesus Christ said:

> Judge not, that ye be not judged. <sup>2</sup> For with what judgment ye judge, ye
>   shall be judged: and with what measure ye mete, it shall be measured
>   to you again. <sup>3</sup> And why beholdest thou the mote that is in thy
>   brother's eye, but considerest not the beam that is in thine own eye?
>   <sup>4</sup> Or how wilt thou say to thy brother, Let me pull out the mote out of
>   thine eye; and, behold, a beam is in thine own eye? <sup>5</sup> Thou hypocrite,
>   first cast out the beam out of thine own eye; and then shalt thou see
>   clearly to cast out the mote out of thy brother's eye.
>
> Matthew 7:1-5

Jesus is not saying not to "judge" people (whatever that means, I have yet to hear from anyone who quotes this verse), he is saying that you ought not to judge someone hypocritically.

You can say that certain things are evil, and that certain actions that a person is performing (like homosexual activities, I believe) are evil; but you cannot do so while doing those actions yourself.

Answer (score -1):

That's because most religious people (including Christians) have merely belief.

Kierkegaard saw a difference between **faith** and **belief**. Belief is me believing that X is true. Faith is the obsession with a certain belief. Faith is belief pushed to its extreme. A truly religious man (the one with faith) is a schizophrenic whose reality is his religion, since **the body is the sinner** and he's free of the body, therefore he will follow every single commandment and won't commit a sin.

But on the other hand the religion of the majority is merely a belief, these majority still have their sinner body and will eventually follow their desires and sin.

Racism is a major way to deny one's death, but since only the body dies not the self, a person with faith won't need denial methods such as racism, unlike the majority:--

> When confronted with reminders of death, we react by criticizing and punishing those who oppose or violate our beliefs, and praising and rewarding those who support or uphold our beliefs. (*The worm at the core: on the role of death in life*)